# Why doesn't Xamarin allow certain file names on Android?

Tags: c#, android, xamarin, xamarin.forms, xamarin.android

I noticed that if you have an image file (png or svg and possibly non-image files too) and wanted to rename it to `default.png`, `public.svg`, etc., then Android will throw a compiler error with `Invalid symbol: [file name]`. I've read somewhere that this is because these are C# reserved keywords. What I don't understand is why these keywords have anything to do with file names and why they only seem to be causing an issue on Android but not other platforms. Is this a bug or by design?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

It is "by design"...

In the build process, first a tool called Android Asset Packaging Tool (`aapt` and `aapt2`) is run that produces a Java file called `R.java` that maps resource names to int values. (Note: aapt|2 is a Google Android tool, not a MSFT/Xamarin one)

So a drawable named `public.png` would generate something like the following in the R.java file:

```
public static int public=0x7f020023;
```

And these values are also mapped into the C# world by Xamarin via the auto-generated `Resource.designer.cs` file, and thus

```
public const int public = 2130837539;
```

And the use of these language keywords as variable names in the Java/C# files will cause compilation errors.